# Run regression by group and paste into original data frame for predict values - sample code provided

Tags: r, rstudio, regression, predict

I have a code that works to produce automated regressions. But I am struggling how to implement a predict function to paste predictions into original data set for each date.

Thank you,

Code I have thus far:

```
test = df[(df$key==1 | df$key==2),]

df_list=split(test, test$key)
reg_results = lapply(df_list,function(temp) {

  good_cols=sapply(temp,function(x){
    is.numeric(x) && ((max(x)-min(x))>10000)
  })

  temp=temp[,good_cols]
  fit=step(lm(y~.,data=temp))
  return(fit)
})

df_list_summary = lapply(reg_results, function(model_output){
  broom::tidy(model_output)
})
final_step2 = dplyr::bind_rows(df_list_summary, .id="Key's")
readr::write_csv(final_step2,"test2.csv")
```

Sample df:

```
   Key  Date                     y   x1   x2   x3
   1    1/10/2018 12:00:00 AM    2   3    2    5
   1    1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   5    7    2
   1    1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM    5   7    4    7 
   1    1/13/2018 12:00:00 AM    7   2    7    6
   2    1/10/2018 12:00:00 AM    2   6    3    8
   2    1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   7    7    3
   2    1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   2    3    4
   2    1/13/2018 12:00:00 AM    7   6    2    7
```

Desired result:

```
   Key  Date                     y   x1   x2   x3  predicted values for each date
   1    1/10/2018 12:00:00 AM    2   3    2    5   ...
   1    1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   5    7    2   ...
   1    1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM    5   7    4    7   ...
   1    1/13/2018 12:00:00 AM    7   2    7    6   ...
   2    1/10/2018 12:00:00 AM    2   6    3    8   ...
   2    1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   7    7    3   ...
   2    1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   2    3    4   ...
   2    1/13/2018 12:00:00 AM    7   6    2    7   ...
```

What I tried thus far to no avail:

```
test2 = df[(df$key==1 | df$key==2),]

unsplit(lapply(split(test, test$key),function(w){
reg_results = lapply(df_list,function(temp) {

  good_cols=sapply(temp,function(x){
    is.numeric(x) && ((max(x)-min(x))>10000)
  })

  temp=temp[,good_cols]
  fit=lm(y~.,data=temp)
})
  cbind(w,predict(fit,subset(df, key=="1" | key=="2")))
}),test$key)

df_list_summary = lapply(reg_results, function(model_output){
  broom::tidy(model_output)
})
final_step2 = dplyr::bind_rows(df_list_summary, .id="key's")
readr::write_csv(final_step2,"test2.csv")
```

UPDATE:
So MrFlick's code has worked; however, I am trying to figure out how to apply the code to the out_of_sample_df. Could anyone assist?

```
 test = df[(df$key==1 | df$key==2),]

df_list=split(test, test$key)
reg_results = lapply(df_list,function(temp) {

  good_cols=sapply(temp,function(x){
    is.numeric(x) && ((max(x)-min(x))>10000)
  })

  temp=temp[,good_cols]
  fit=step(lm(y~.,data=temp))
  return(fit)
})


#MrFlicks contribution - need help to adjust this line of code to apply to out of sample data to produce prediction results. Currently this line of code inserts pred column inside original data set.

    reg_predict = dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(data, model) {
           data.frame(data, pred=predict(model))    }, df_list, reg_results))


df_list_summary = lapply(reg_results, function(model_output){
  broom::tidy(model_output)
})
final_step2 = dplyr::bind_rows(df_list_summary, .id="Key's")
readr::write_csv(final_step2,"test2.csv")
```

Thank you,

Comment: Where exactly are you getting stuck? What did you try? What's the specific problem you are running into?

Comment: I am trying a variety of aspects, I am unable to get the predict function to apply to the specified space. updated OP to show my trial and error thus far

Comment: @MrFlick would you kindly be able to assist with the below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map()` to iterate over both the data and the models to get the result you are after. Starting with the original code, you can do soemthing like this

```
reg_predict = dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(data, model) {
    data.frame(data, pred=predict(model))
}, df_list, reg_results))
```

Comment: Hi MrFlick, could you guide me as to where this line of code would go to incorporate into my original?

Comment: Hi MrFlick, thank you kindly, I believe it worked when I put it near the bottom of my initial code. If I wanted to predict out of sample test, and change the df, since this is insample prediction. How can I adjust the code correctly? Here is what I tried and I am getting errors:

`reg_predict = dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(data, model) {
  data.frame(data, pred=predict(model,subset(df_outofsample,key==1 | key==2))
}, df_list, reg_results))`

Comment: Since the initial code produces a regression, I would like to adjust the code you made to create a prediction on a dataframe that is out of sample and include its fit as your code above does. This currently adjusts my existing data set. If that makes sense.

Comment: Appreciate if anyone can assist, still can't figure it out . . .